# How to use geoserver to display data on hosted website

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, web-mapping

I am using geoserver to display GIS data on my hosted website
when geoserver is running I can see my data on my website in both firefox and Internet explorer but only on my laptop where I have geoserver running, when I try to view the website using Firefox or IE on another PC I just get a blank box with error on page warning on the bottom of the web browser. can anyone help with this thanks

Comment: If you have the time and chance, consider going through the tutorial they provide and workshop

Answer (score 4):

How are you getting your layer with openlayers?

If you are passing the url as "localhost:8181/geoserver" javascript won't find it because JavaScript works on the client side. Also, JavaScript can only access geoserver if its on the same host ([for security reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). You'll have to set up a proxy for geoserver so you can access geoserver from yourhost/geoserver instead of yourhost:8181/geoserver.

Comment: yes i am using localhost:8181/geoserver, i am anew user to geoserver is it difficult to setup a proxy for geoserver?

Comment: @ghostface It depends on what web server you are using

Comment: Try this: http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoServer+Proxy+Extension

Comment: iam using a hosted website buy a comapny called 1&1

Comment: i have set up a proxy using my website url, and entered website url into the formula supplied @ http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoServer+Proxy+Extension but its not clear where i should at this into the text file

Comment: you need to host your geoserver on a shared (using apache webserver) PC or server - localhost will only be accessible from your laptop without it. http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html

Comment: @mapperz is this http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html for linux user only i have windows vista

Comment: @ghost I might suggest contacting your host to see if you are allowed to change the servers configuration settings (so can set up a proxy), and if you can install geoserver on on their web server.